# Is there any possibilty to show the general location of the users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is actually Yvette Colomb's suggestion.

Is there a possibility to make the general location of users shown in the Q&A section of the pages? And if it is possible to make this, is it possible to make it a mouse-over to show the location?

This will make it easier to answer questions if the location is known. I know this will be on a voluntary  basis of every user.

So, is it possible to change the profile page with an option to share my location or don't share my location? An answer to a question might often be dependent on where in the world a person lives and what resources are available there.

Please share your views on this suggestion. I myself think this is a good idea and that it might make this site even better. If anybody has other suggestions on how to do this, your input is not only wanted but also needed, so let's make this site even better.

And this concludes my first question here on meta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a two part answer to this.

**Part 1**

Existing tools; Currently a user can choose to display their location in their profile.

1. Go to your profile page (from the [main pets.se,](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) not META where we are now)
2. Click on you profile image near top center of web page.
3. Click on "Edit Profile & Settings", and enter the location you would like to display.

To view the displayed location

1. Click on the users name in the question or answer.
2. Go to the profile tab, if populated it will be right side of the screen with other user details.
   Example [users/13/james-jenkins?tab=profile](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13/james-jenkins?tab=profile)

**Part 2**

Having the location display on mouse over would require a change to the web design.  This would be controlled by SE staff. It would probably require that all sites in the SE family be modified.  You can request the feature by posting a new question at https://meta.stackexchange.com/ with the tag "feature-request"

There is a post that says location was [once available in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69416/add-location-and-timezone-to-chat-profile) but has been discontinued.

Answer (score 4):

As said in the other [answer](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2176/9803) by [James Jenkins](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13/james-jenkins), that information is already available, opt-in style, in the user profiles. If the information is there, then you can use that to help answer the question. If it's not there, adding some form of mouse-over behavior to the site wouldn't help anyway.

In most cases that the location of the OP matters to the possible answers, the OP should realize this and give that information in the question. Even if that information *is* in their profile. If the OP doesn't provide that information, and it is important to the answer, then you can use comments to suggest that a good answer depends on knowing where in the world they are.

As to the possibility of the feature being added, I'd speculate that it's not going to happen. The Stack Exchange model is to provide answers that will have value to many future visitors, as well as the OP, and in these cases, the OP's location would be important to the question for those future visitors as well, and so it *should* be in the question itself, not tied to the OP's profile. The OP could move from one place to another, and the answers based on the original location, would then *look* like they were meant for the new location, and be wrong.

Comment: Also, a user might later decide not to publicize location and the info would go away, or a user account could be deleted, or a post could be anonymized (disassociated).  Everything that's important to answering a question should be in the question.